# nswag generates proxy which spoils the URL

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0, swagger-codegen, nswag

The general idea of `nswag` software is amazing.

The guys have totally ruined it though.

I'm really now thinking of dropping it for the following reasons:

- overcomplicated
- problematic
- extremely poorly documented
- unpopular

Regarding my version - `"nswag@11.17.19"`.

My service is supposed to pass a compound structure (e.g. nested arrays) - but in recent versions it passes all of the content via the URL and here's what I mean:

[image]

Moreover, recent versions of it don't generate input classes - e.g. my API controller has action `ImportEntries(ImportEntriesInput input)`

`nswag` no longer generates input class (I mean `ImportEntriesInput`) - instead it just lists all of its members:

For example compare

```
importEntries(input: ImportEntriesInput | null | undefined): Observable<VocabularyDto> {
```

with

```
importEntries(entries: CrawlerEntryDto[] | null | undefined, vocabularyId: number | undefined, newVocabulary: boolean | undefined, typeId: number | undefined, name: string | null | undefined, notes: string | null | undefined): Observable<VocabularyDto | null> {
```

Maybe the guys who develop it find it okay, but I'd say this totally overcomplicates the whole approach and is **too bad**.

I wasn't really able to find documentation covering this part.

Anyone knows how to solve this?

---

Also, here's the bit where it creates the content being passes in URL:

```
importEntries(entries: CrawlerEntryDto[] | null | undefined, vocabularyId: number | undefined, newVocabulary: boolean | undefined, typeId: number | undefined, name: string | null | undefined, notes: string | null | undefined): Observable<VocabularyDto | null> {
    let url_ = this.baseUrl + "/api/Import/ImportEntries?";
    if (entries !== undefined)
        entries && entries.forEach((item, index) => { 
            for (let attr in item)
                url_ += "entries[" + index + "]." + attr + "=" + encodeURIComponent("" + item[attr]) + "&";
        });
    if (vocabularyId === null)
        throw new Error("The parameter 'vocabularyId' cannot be null.");
    else if (vocabularyId !== undefined)
        url_ += "vocabularyId=" + encodeURIComponent("" + vocabularyId) + "&"; 
    if (newVocabulary === null)
        throw new Error("The parameter 'newVocabulary' cannot be null.");
    else if (newVocabulary !== undefined)
        url_ += "newVocabulary=" + encodeURIComponent("" + newVocabulary) + "&"; 
    if (typeId === null)
        throw new Error("The parameter 'typeId' cannot be null.");
    else if (typeId !== undefined)
        url_ += "typeId=" + encodeURIComponent("" + typeId) + "&"; 
    if (name !== undefined)
        url_ += "name=" + encodeURIComponent("" + name) + "&"; 
    if (notes !== undefined)
        url_ += "notes=" + encodeURIComponent("" + notes) + "&"; 
    url_ = url_.replace(/[?&]$/, "");

    let options_ : any = {
        observe: "response",
        responseType: "blob",
        headers: new HttpHeaders({
            "Content-Type": "application/json", 
            "Accept": "application/json",
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('token')
        })
    };

    return this.http.request("post", url_, options_).flatMap((response_ : any) => {
        return this.processImportEntries(response_);
    }).catch((response_: any) => {
        if (response_ instanceof HttpResponseBase) {
            try {
                return this.processImportEntries(<any>response_);
            } catch (e) {
                return <Observable<VocabularyDto | null>><any>Observable.throw(e);
            }
        } else
            return <Observable<VocabularyDto | null>><any>Observable.throw(response_);
    });
}
```

**Quite appalling, isn't it?**

`swaggerToTypeScriptClient` bit from config:

```
"codeGenerators": {
    "swaggerToTypeScriptClient": {
      "className": "{controller}ServiceProxy",
      "moduleName": "",
      "namespace": "",
      "typeScriptVersion": 2.0,
      "template": "Angular",
      "promiseType": "Promise",
        "httpClass": "HttpClient",
      "dateTimeType": "MomentJS",
      "nullValue": "Undefined",
      "generateClientClasses": true,
      "generateClientInterfaces": false,
      "generateOptionalParameters": false,
      "wrapDtoExceptions": false,
      "wrapResponses": false,
      "generateResponseClasses": true,
      "responseClass": "SwaggerResponse",
      "useTransformOptionsMethod": false,
      "useTransformResultMethod": false,
      "generateDtoTypes": true,
      "operationGenerationMode": "MultipleClientsFromPathSegments"
      "markOptionalProperties": false,
      "generateCloneMethod": true,
      "typeStyle": "Class",
      "extensionCode": "service.extensions.ts",
      "generateDefaultValues": true,
      "excludedTypeNames": [],
      "handleReferences": false,
      "generateConstructorInterface": true,
      "importRequiredTypes": true,
      "useGetBaseUrlMethod": false,
      "baseUrlTokenName": "API_BASE_URL",
      "injectionTokenType": "InjectionToken",
      "output": "../src/shared/service-proxies/service-proxies.ts"
    },
```

Comment: I'll probably add this as comment - really, `nswag` wasn't even able to include additional header for JWT authentication, however I've specified it in `Startup.cs`.
`new SwaggerSecurityScheme
                    {
                        Type = SwaggerSecuritySchemeType.ApiKey,
                        Name = "Authorization",
                        Description = "Copy 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('token')",
                        In = SwaggerSecurityApiKeyLocation.Header...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This fixes the issue with URL mentioned in my post above.**

That wasn't documented, but in order for `nswag` to work properly with ASP.NET Core you are meant to apply `[FromBody]` attribute to every action accepting data

e.g.

```
public async Task<VocabularyDto> ImportEntries([FromBody] ImportEntriesInput input)
```